# python - pdfkit from url to PDF

Tags: python, jira, pdfkit

I'm trying to convert Web Page to PDF using the code below.

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url(str(url), 'out.pdf')
```

But I need first to register to the web.

How can I Add username and password as parameters in the Url??

Comment: umm thats not how it works

Answer (score 0):

Best option is transmitting a cookie of a connected user to pdfkit.

1. Login normally by sending credentials using urllib or anything that can do http request.
2. Retrieve cookie sends by server from headers
3. `pdfkit.from_url(str(url), 'out.pdf', options={ cookie: 'cookiename cookievalue' })`